# JSON array in html table

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach, html-table

I have a json array, looks like:

```
 Array ( 
[0] => Array
    (
        [k1] => aaa
        [k2] => aaa
    [kTypes] => Array
            (
                [ktype1] => Array
                    (
                        [desc] => asd
                    )

                [ktype2] => Array
                    (
                        [desc] => asd
                    )

            )

    )
```

And I try to get the desc values inside ktypes, tried this:

```
$items = $myArray;
// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($items);
// echo "</pre>";

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><th>k1</th><th>k2</th><th>ktype1</th><th>ktype2</th></tr>';
foreach($items as $item)
{
echo "<tr><td>$item[k1]</td><td>$item[k2]</td><td>$item[kTypes][kType1][desc]</td><td>$item[kTypes][kType2][desc]</td>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

which works fine for the first both columns, but not the ktype ones. There the:

```
echo is "Array[kType2][desc]"
```

So I tried a nested loop, but this didn't work, too.

can anyone help me on the right track?

Comment: Why are you using a loop anyway? The loop would iterate through your array so $item would be $items[k1] in the beginning, next $items[k2] and so on...

Comment: @Rsauxil I think you didn't notice `[0]` at the top. It's an indexed array whose elements are associative arrays.

Comment: @barmar: that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To interpolate multidimensional array accesses in a string, you have to use the "complex" format with curly braces.

```
echo "<tr><td>$item[k1]</td><td>$item[k2]</td><td>{$item['kTypes']['kType1']['desc']}</td><td>{$item['kTypes']['kType2']['desc']}</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this foreach for your specific piece:

```
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($items as $field => $value) {
     if($field =='ktype'} {
           foreach($items['ktype'] as $ktype) {
                 foreach($ktype as $k) {
                      echo "<td>{$k}</td>";
                 }
           }
     } else {
          echo "<td>{$value}</td>";
     }
}
echo "</tr>";
```

However, I would do a recursive piece so it can go as deep into the array as possible.